# flexbox flex-basis column distribution

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container that has up to 6 child elements their widths are 16.666667% minus it's gutter of 10px. I can create the grid with six items and they get evenly distributed in the flex-row but the problem I'm having is when I only have 5 items the child elements do not distribute evenly when I compare two grids together. So when I have only five elements there is a 5px or so added extra to each element because their isn't a 6th item how do I fix this so that both grid are lining up. What I don't want happening is the redistribution of spaces for 5 columns instead of 6

```css
.flex-grid {
  background: green;
}

.flex-grid .flex-row {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-grid .flex-1-6-5 {
  flex: calc( 16.6666666667% - 10px);
  /* I've tried flex: 0 0 calc() */
}

.flex-grid.flex-gutter-5>.flex-row>div:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.box {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid flex-gutter-5 six-columns">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">1</div>
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">2</div>
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">3</div>
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">4</div>
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">5</div>
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-grid flex-gutter-5 five-columns" style="margin-top: 40px">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">1</div>
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">2</div>
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">3</div>
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">4</div>
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You say you've tried `flex: 0 0 calc(...)`. But that seems to work. What's the problem with it? https://jsfiddle.net/4L8sgnek/1/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a `max-width` of `calc(16.6666666667% - 10px)` might do the trick.

```css
.flex-grid {
  background: green;
}

.flex-grid .flex-row {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-grid .flex-1-6-5 {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: calc( 16.6666666667% - 10px);
}

.flex-grid.flex-gutter-5>.flex-row>div:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.box {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid flex-gutter-5 six-columns">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">1</div>
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">2</div>
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">3</div>
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">4</div>
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">5</div>
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-grid flex-gutter-5 five-columns" style="margin-top: 40px">
  <div class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">1</div>
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">2</div>
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">3</div>
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">4</div>
    <div class="flex-1-6-5 box">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah I can get that result as well but the problem is the remainder on on the last item in the row you can see a green background, why are they not stretching all the way across

Comment: How can 5 elements by aligned with 6 elements, _and_ stretch the full width?

Comment: Are you saying you want the 5th item in the row with 5 elements to fill the remaining space?

Comment: no I don't want the 5th one using the remaining space filled I just want them distributed equally with no green spaces on the end on the first grid and the second grid matching

Comment: There must be something wrong with the calc function method because I can't get % to fill up the remaining space especially for the first grid but then have the second grid reflect but with only 5 elements

Comment: It does appear you're using `flex` incorrectly, it should be something like `flex: 1`, but I don't think that's causing any issues, for now. Can you create a mockup of what you want? It's unclear how you want a row with 5 elements to match a row with 6 elements.

Comment: Is this what you want - https://imgur.com/a/btaSJ?